# Touching the screen with two fingers invokes a one-finger method

Tags: java, android

I invoke method `finger2()` when user touches the screen by 2 fingers and make zoom in and zoom out `(ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener)` It works.
But recently I add new method `finger1()` which reacts on touches the screen by touches and move in left or right `(GestureDetector.OnGestureListener)`- this method detects only 1 finger. It also works.
**And now I have problem** when the user wants to put 2 fingers on the screen, first is invoke a method from 1 finger and then method from 2 fingers.
How to fix this fail? I would like the `finger1()` method not triggered when touched by 2 fingers.

```
public class SwipeListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
     public static final int MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE = 40; 


    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
       float xDiff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
       float yDiff = e1.getY() - e2.getY();
       return resolveSwipe(xDiff, yDiff);
    }


    private boolean resolveSwipe(float xDist, float yDist) {
        float yDistAbs = Math.abs(yDist);
        float xDistAbs = Math.abs(xDist);

        SwipeDirection swipeDirection;


        if (yDistAbs > xDistAbs) {
            if (yDistAbs < MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE) {return false;}
            swipeDirection = (yDist > 0) ? SwipeDirection.DOWN: SwipeDirection.UP;

        } else {
            if (xDistAbs < MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE) {return false;}
            swipeDirection = (xDist > 0) ? SwipeDirection.RIGHT: SwipeDirection.LEFT;
        }

        onSwipeEvent(swipeDirection);
        return true;
    }

    private void onSwipeEvent(SwipeDirection swipeDirection) {
        if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.UP) {

            return;
        }
        if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.DOWN) {

            return;
        }
        if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.LEFT) {
         finger1()
            return;
        }
        if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.RIGHT) {
            finger1();
            return;
        }

}

public enum SwipeDirection {
    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
}
```

}

Comment: Because it seems like you don't ask if the swipe was done with 1 or multiple fingers. You need to keep in mind that a swipe can easily be detected when trying to zoom.

Comment: but how to do that ?